# {$IMAGEBASE $13140000} directive in a unit from an advanced hooking / injection library: explanation needed

Tags: image, delphi, hook, code-injection, radix

**What I have done so far:**

I found it in the [AfxCodeHook.pas](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/afxcodehookbyaphex) unit by Aphex.

I have also skimmed a bunch of interesting sample codes using it:

- [Inject Library](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/afxcodehookexample-injectlibrary) (how to inject a DLL into another process).
- [Inject Library Ex](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/afxcodehookexample-injectlibraryex) (how to inject a DLL into another process using the Ex method).
- [Create Process Ex](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/afxcodehookexample-createprocessex) (how to inject a DLL into a created process using the Ex method).
- [Inject Executable](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/afxcodehookexample-injectexecutable) (InjectLibraryEx's true power: the ability to inject EXE files).
- [Simple Api Hooking](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/afxcodehookexample-simpleapihooking) (how to use afxcodehook to manipulate calls to windows apis).

I have also read:

- Embarcadero's RAD Studio help entry on [`Image base address`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Image_base_address) and
- [`Base address`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_address) page in Wikipedia.

---

**Question:**

I seek for an informed opinion and a simple explanation of the {$IMAGEBASE $13140000} directive in Layman's Terms from seasoned Delphi coders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specifies the preferred base address of the DLL. If the DLL can be loaded at this address, then the loader will do so. If it cannot, then it needs to be relocated and all the absolute jumps in the DLL need to be adjusted to the new address.

When the loader attempts to map a DLL into a process address space, it first reads the preferred base address. Then it works out the size of the DLL. Finally it checks to see if a contiguous block of memory stretching from the base address to the base address + size can be found. If so then the DLL is loaded at the preferred base address. If another DLL, or the exe resides at the preferred base address, then the DLL will need to be relocated. If the application has reserved heap memory that overlaps with the preferred DLL load address space, then the DLL will need to be relocated.

If a DLL needs to be relocated then its physical pages cannot be shared between processes. The Windows system DLLs have carefully chosen base addresses to ensure that there are no collisions and that they can be shared.

Nowadays, [Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) complicates matters even further.

You can learn more from these articles:

- [Dr. Dobbs: Rebasing Win32 DLLs](http://www.drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=184416272&siteSectionName=windows)
- [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the value $13140000 was chose?

Comment: @menjaraz - Are you able to hook/inject when you remove/change the base address?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author. It looks a poor choice though, based on the Dr. Dobbs article. In practice it seldom matters because relocation is quick.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: I just compiled it under Delphi 7 without change and run it on VMWare. It works but I'm suspicious of any code injection ;-) I'll check and report afterward.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Spot the relevant info I need in the Dr. Dobbs' article. You are right.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Does all that apply also for Exe files? Some sample using AfxCodeHook.pas targets Exes.

Comment: @menjaraz By convention executables all use a base address of `$00400000`. I'm not sure what you are concerned about. You understand that the system will automatically and transparently relocate any DLL that needs it. Or are you using some technique that will fail in the face of relocation?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: Stripped of the directive and tried with 2 samples targeting exe files (Windows XP/WMware). It's Ok sofar.

Comment: AfxCodeHook.pas is also used in unit targeting exe file. My understanding of it is that the directive in that case impacts the exe.

Comment: @menjaraz - Then the author probably wanted to avoid time spent relocating the image, however small it may be..